# Getting xtick and ytick on a polar stereographic plot with matplotlib / python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I kind of know that my problem is probably super simple, but I can not solve it.

I use Basemap to plot a polarstereographic map of the arctic, but I am not able to plot the longitude values on the axis. I want to have the values of the coordinates plotted on the axis.

My code looks the following at the moment:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=70,lon_0=270,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81,10.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.))
plt.show()
```

I'm thankful for any advice.

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what your problem is? At least the code does what one would expect (except for the coastlines, because of a typo in your example code -- I will fix this shortly).

Comment: @ThomasKühn I have no numbers at the axis (I think it is called ticks). And I want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `Basemap` explicitly that you want labels. You cannot do this with the usual `set_xticklabels()` command, because `basemap` does not use this functionality, but instead draws its labels differently. Instead, use the keyword `labels` in the `drawmeridians()` function. In particular, the following command

```
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.), labels=[True, True, True, True])
```

will draw labels on all four sides of the map. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/graticule.html) for more details.